# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback

Tags: android

I got this error when I try to run my app:

> Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback

Here is my build.gradle(app)

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.madhvi.electric"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

Here is my build.gradle(project)

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any solution to this problem? I already try everything I know of course, but I'm new on this, I really don't know what cause the error apart from what the console says

Comment: Can you post the code where you're getting the error from?

Answer (score 1):

Enable `multidex` in your application :

Add this in the app level `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Add this in defaultConfig:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.madhvi.electric"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when migrating to androidx, the problem was that I was including the same thing twice. Try removing the last package and sync again. If that doesn't work, remove one at a time to see which is causing the clash.

Answer (score 0):

Some old libraries using older support version.

Check conflicted dependencies using this command ./gradlew app:dependencies

Then Remove all conflict dependencies like this

```
 implementation ('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

This work for me.